# Vim-latex key expansion doesn't remove the typed keys

Tags: vim

I recently installed vim-latex plugin in gvim 7.4. I followed the documentation to set it up. Everything is working. But I have a problem. When I type in key expansion combination, the combination keys are also left with the expanded result. For example, pressing `` `^ `` should   expands to   `\Hat{<++>}<++>`. But it instead expands to

```
`^\Hat{<++>}<++>
```

this is true for all. some examples

```
`D\Delta
SSS\subsection{}<++>
SPG\paragraph{}<++>
SSP\subparagraph{}<++>
```

How can I solved this problem so that the key combination gets omitted when expansion happens?

Comment: From what I read here, vim-latex often seems to create more problems then it solves. There are numerous other plugins which perform all sorts of things, but for snippets I suggest looking at [snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate), and a suitable snippet file for TeX can be found [here](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/snippets/tex.snippets). They are also very easy to adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The following change to line `290` of the `~/.vim/plugin/imaps.vim` file did the trick for me:

**before**:

`return a:char . "\<c-g>u\<bs>" . bs . IMAP_PutTextWithMovement(rhs, phs, phe)`

**after**:

`return  bs . "\<c-g>u\<bs>" . IMAP_PutTextWithMovement(rhs, phs, phe)`

---

*I have never before tempered with vim-script, so it might be, that this solution only works with my particular compilation of vim.*

*Also, I have not yet testet all of the mappings done via vim-latex IMAP and it could be, that the `a:char` is important for some of them.*

Answer (score 0):

Just add `set backspace=start` to the `.vimrc` will solve this problem.
Because `<bs>` cannot delete the character before the undo point when `backspace` is not set.

In the file `~/.vim/plugin/imaps.vim`, in the end of the function `s:LookupCharacter` there is some code like this:

```
let bs = substitute(s:MultiByteStrpart(lhs, 1), ".", "\<bs>", "g")
" \<c-g>u inserts an undo point
return a:char . "\<c-g>u\<bs>" . bs . IMAP_PutTextWithMovement(rhs, phs, phe)
```

The last line return what you have entered, and then creat an undo point use `\<c-g>u`, and then use several `<bs>` to delete the characters you have entered.
However, when `backspace` is not set, `<bs>` cannot delete the character entered before the undo point.

The var `bs` is several `backspace` used to delete what you have entered.